# After updating sudoers user still does not have access to sudo

Tags: sudo, osx-snow-leopard

I'm having problems adding a user to the sudoers list via the /etc/sudoers file.

```
$ whoami
iain
```

And they said I was crazy!

```
$ which visudo
/usr/sbin/visudo

$ ls -la /usr/sbin/visudo
---x--x--x  1 root  wheel  186768 23 Jun  2009 /usr/sbin/visudo


$ sudo su -
Password:
macbook:~ root# whoami
root
macbook:~ root# visudo
```

The file opens in vi:

```
# this line is the one I added to sudoers
# I gave ALL as access to try and get this to work
# it's the same setting as my account, which works.
%yvonne         ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

I save the file. It shows "unchanged" here because I'd already done it.

```
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
macbook:~ root# logout
```

Log in as yvonne…

```
$ sudo su - yvonne

yvonne@87 02/08/2013 19:34 $ whoami
yvonne
```

Try to run anything via `sudo`:

```
yvonne@88 02/08/2013 19:34 $ sudo ls

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
**yvonne is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.**
```

I'm perplexed, can anyone give me any help or insight so that I can give the `yvonne` account access to `sudo`? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%` is the group assignment operator in sudoers. I think you want the line to read:

```
yvonne         ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: You are right. The group has been added as `yvonnes`, which is why this didn't work at all, so a typo has led to me learning something. Many thanks.

Comment: Zypher is correct.  "%yvonne" means all members of the "yvonne" group.  This may work in your case if your user is a member of a group with the same name as your user.

Comment: @Insyte yes, previously all users have had a corresponding group with the same name added. This one had a typo because I set it up on the fly with someone trying to micromanage me over my shoulder :/ Unhelpful, but now I've fixed 2 problems with one question so things are looking up! :)